# Clearing The IsEscalated Checkbox After Submitting The Escalation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I had a business requirement to check the IsEscalated checkbox once a button is clicked. That all works fine now but once I click that button I get the message that the case is escalated for all the cases even if that box is not checked for that particular case. I tried unchecking that button for the cases where it was checked and it didn't make a difference.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasSObjectName,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

    <aura:attribute name="case" type="case" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!IsEscalated!= 'false'}">
        <p> This case is already escalated</p>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <lightning:button label="Escalate" onclick="{!c.escalate}" aura:id="Escalate"/>
            <lightning:card iconName="standard:case" title="Escalate Case" class="slds-hide" aura:id="Title">
                <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                          objectApiName="Case">
                    <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
                    <lightning:messages />
                    <div aura:id="toggleArea" class="slds-hide">
                        <div style="padding:15px;" class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <lightning:inputField aura:id="IsEscalated" fieldName="IsEscalated"/>
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Escalation_Type__c" />
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Escalation_Details__c" />
                                <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                                    <lightning:button aura:id="SaveEscalation" variant="brand" type="submit" label="Save" onclick="{!c.submit}" />
                                    <lightning:button aura:id="CancelEscalation" variant="brand" type="cancel" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancel}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </lightning:recordEditForm>
            </lightning:card>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    submit : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.util.removeClass(component.find("Escalate"), "slds-hide");
        $A.util.addClass(component.find("Title"), "slds-hide");        
        $A.util.addClass(component.find("toggleArea"), "slds-hide");
        component.find("IsEscalated").set("v.value", true);

        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");  
        toastEvent.setParams({  
            "title": "Success!",  
            "message": "Record is successfully updated!",  
            "type": "success"  
        });  
        toastEvent.fire();
        component.find("IsEscalated").set("v.value", '');

    },
    cancel : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.util.removeClass(component.find("Escalate"), "slds-hide");
        $A.util.addClass(component.find("Title"), "slds-hide");        
        $A.util.addClass(component.find("toggleArea"), "slds-hide");
    },
    escalate : function(component, event, helper) {
        $A.util.addClass(component.find("Escalate"), "slds-hide");
        $A.util.removeClass(component.find("Title"), "slds-hide");
        $A.util.removeClass(component.find("toggleArea"), "slds-hide");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`IsEscalated` is not defined, and you did not use a value provider (`v`). You need to define the attribute, and use the appropriate value provider. Here's the necessary changes:

```
<aura:attribute name="IsEscalated" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.IsEscalated}">
```

Note that `'false'` (with quotes) is a `true` value, which is why there'd be some odd behavior as well. You'll want to read about [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) for more information about how Boolean values work in JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't IsEscalated already defined in     <aura:attribute name="case" type="case" />? I changed the if to     <aura:if isTrue="{!v.case.IsEscalated}"> but now the button shows up and the escalation message doesn't.

Comment: @LauraBejjani Your code in the question is incorrect, at minimum. If you mean to use IsEscalated on the case, it needs to be `{!v.case.IsEscalated}`, not `{!IsEscalated}`. You also need to make sure your variable is initialized (which is not shown in your code either).

Comment: Sorry I'm new to SF Development.<lightning:inputField aura:id="IsEscalated" fieldName="IsEscalated"/> is checked so it must be initialized at this point but I still can't get it to work. What I need is to only make that button and the escalation type and escalation details available if the case isn't already escalated.